# Linux boot commands for memory boot on am335x

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, u-boot

I am using am335x based custom board. I have only uart port for loading images to memory. I was able to get u-boot working. What are the load addresses for the linux kernel and the dts file. What will be boot command for running the loaded kernel from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DDR on Am335x starts at address 0x80000000. The ending address depends on the size of your DDR RAM. For a 128MB RAM, you have the last addres at 0x88000000 So you can load your kernel anywhere. Make sure you load the device tree blob toward the end of the RAM and set the following for u-boot
setenv fdt_high 0x88000000
This ensures that fdt is not relocated outside the max address of your ram.
Your basic bootargs will be
console=ttyO0,115200n8 earlyprintk=serial mem=128m
Anything else depends on your rootfs which can be on mmc or sd.

Answer (score 0):

Refer TI AM335x links for loading kernel and dtb images from different places,
below links explains load address as well commands to load and run,

1. [AM335x User's Guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AM335x_PSP_User%27s_Guide)
2. [AMSDK u-boot User's Guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/AMSDK_u-boot_User%27s_Guide)